# search full-text with wildcard in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, wildcard

I want to search this phrase "any string that has AT1 or any string that has pro" in filed "text". this is part of my query :

```
"query_string" : {
                "query" : "text:*AT1* *pro*",
                "fields" : [ ],
                "use_dis_max" : true,
                "tie_breaker" : 0.0,
                "default_operator" : "or",
                "auto_generate_phrase_queries" : false,
                "max_determinized_states" : 10000,
                "enable_position_increments" : true,
                "fuzziness" : "AUTO",
                "fuzzy_prefix_length" : 0,
                "fuzzy_max_expansions" : 50,
                "phrase_slop" : 0,
                "escape" : false,
                "split_on_whitespace" : true,
                "boost" : 1.0,
                "allow_leading_wildcard": true, 
                "analyze_wildcard":true
              }
```

but it doesn't work.it shows all documents.where is my problem?

Comment: which library are you using to build this query as we would have to make a  wildcard query for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "text",
      "query": "at1 AND pro"
    }
  }
}
```

Also, you can read the documentation about [full-text queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/full-text-queries.html) and [compound queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/compound-queries.html) because exists a many ways to solve your problem

Comment: but this query doesn't response completely.I want any text has at1 or pro for example "asdsfdAT1" or "sadfsfdAT1asdd" andd ..... .I can use two query string separately , "query" : "text:*AT1*" and  "query" : "text:*pro*", but I want two ,merge these query string. I test this query  "query" : "text:*AT1* *pro*" but didn't work

Comment: Then use edge_ngram analyzer start from min_gram=3. This will be more efficient from wildcards...